# Handlebars #each within #if issue

Tags: handlebars.js

I have an #if condition that I have tested is false, but it enters anyway. Here is the Handlebar script :

```
{{#each this.properties}}
    <span class="values">
        {{#if is-object-property}}
            {{#each values}}
                <span class="value" style="color:blue;">{{this}}</span>
            {{/each}}
        {{else}}
            {{#each values}}
                <span class="value">{{this}}</span>
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    </span>
{{/each}}
```

The thing is that all I have displayed is blue while my object looks like that:

```
properties: Array[3]
 0: Object
  code: "pays"
  reliability: 100
  values: Array[1]
 1: Object
  code: "pnb"
  reliability: 100
  values: Array[1]
 2: Object
  code: "source"
  is-object-property: "true"
  reliability: 100
  values: Array[2]
```

And as you can see, except for the object 2, the objects 0 and 1 should have an `undefined` result for `is-object-property`. They do have that result, that's why I don't understand why I have all in blue.

I assumed it entered the condition, but as it is written on the handlebars website : "You can use the if helper to conditionally render a block. If its argument returns `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `""` or `[]` (a "falsy" value), Handlebars will not render the block."

(see "The if block helper" at http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem :

```
<span class="values">
    {{#each values}}
        {{#if ../is-object-property}}
            <span class="value" style="color:blue;">{{this}}</span>
        {{else}}
            <span class="value">{{this}}</span>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</span>
```